# javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unsupported record version Unknown-97.117

Tags: java, exception, ssl, xmpp, asmack

I am getting below exception when I try to login from my local machine to my live XMPP server using `aSmack` library.

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unsupported record version Unknown-97.117
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readV3Record(InputRecord.java:524)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:509)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:927)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:884)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:102)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:283)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:325)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:177)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.read1(BufferedReader.java:203)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.read(BufferedReader.java:279)
    at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.fillBuf(MXParser.java:2992)
    at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.more(MXParser.java:3046)
    at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.parseProlog(MXParser.java:1410)
    at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.nextImpl(MXParser.java:1395)
    at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.next(MXParser.java:1093)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.parsePackets(PacketReader.java:335)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.access$1(PacketReader.java:230)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader$1.run(PacketReader.java:71)
```

This error is `not consistent` for every request, sometimes it works fine, but whenever it occurs, it takes lots of time and gives no error line for my code in stacktrace.

One another thing I tried so many times, I did the same thing from my another live server and I never got this exception.

java -version : 1.6XXX

Is this because of certificate issue? What is the reason for this exception? How can I solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Both http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23324807/randomly-sslexception-unsupported-record-version-unknown-0-0 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24908938/javax-net-ssl-sslexception-unsupported-record-version-unknown-0-2 are very similar errors

Comment: @Joe I searched before ask and I also found those links but none of those links have proper answer.

Comment: Yes, they're certainly not exact duplicates. Did you try different JDKs? Did you try the Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files?